# Modify key of an RDD

Tags: join, key, apache-spark, rdd

My RDD is of below structure -

```
Key| Val1   |Val2  |
314 | 850   |10468.714
315 | 850   |20468.714
316 | 873   |14630.532
317 | 676   |21450.78
318 | 475   |23247.512
319 | 850   |10468.714
320 | 850   |10468.714
321 | 850   |20468.714
322 | 873   |14630.532
323 | 676   |21450.78
324 | 475   |23247.512
```

I Run two filter operations with some offset value -

**Filter Op1:**

Offset = 0 and time scope from 320 to 324

All the keys having value from (320-0) to (324-0) are filtered

FilteredRDD1:

```
Key| Val1   |Val2  |
320 | 850   |10468.714
321 | 850   |20468.714
322 | 873   |14630.532
323 | 676   |21450.78
324 | 475   |23247.512
```

**Filter Op2:**

Offset = 6 and time scope from 320 to 324

All the keys having value from (320-6):314 to (324-6):318 are filtered

FilteredRDD2:

```
Key| Val1   |Val2  |
314 | 850   |10468.714
315 | 850   |20468.714
316 | 873   |14630.532
317 | 676   |21450.78
318 | 475   |23247.512
```

***Action***

I want to **multiply** Val1 from FilteredRDD1 with Val2 from FilteredRDD2.

I can think of an option wherein -

1. Modify key of FilteredRDD2 using offset so that the keys of both the FilteredRDDs are same
2. Do a join on the un-modified FilteredRDD and the modified FilteredRDD
3. Perform a map operation on the joined RDD and multiply Val1 with Val2

Any other better option available so that there is lesser shuffling and lesser intermediate operations.

TIA!

Comment: "I want to multiply Val1 from FilteredRDD1 with Val2 from FilteredRDD1." -> I guess what's meant here is "to multiply Val1 from FilteredRDD1 with Val2 from FilteredRDD**2**. ?

Comment: I think your solution should be ok. Are you having problems with it?

Comment: I just wanted to check if there are better ways of doing it. Though I have found a better way wherein instead of modifying the key and then doing a join, I override the equals and hashcode so that the offset is accounted for when doing comparison for join.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a 'better' way :-) The filter/join/merge is a good, understandable solution. Hacking the equals/hashcode to force fit a key match is more of a hack.